# What happens to existing apache PHP processes when you git push?

Tags: php, mysql, git, apache

Problem: say that an Apache process is currently executing PHP that is performing a very long database query (30 seconds or so). You want to push a fix to optimize the database query.

If you do a `git push`, will this affect PHP processes currently executing, and their respective database queries?

I'm using MySql, PHP and Apache on a linux platform (LAMP setup).

Obviously I'm worried about the PHP code changing mid-database-call.

Comment: NO! The code will have been loaded and Interpreted. The running process will be using the Interpreted(compiled) executable version of the source

Comment: So code changes via `git push` are only applied to new PHP processes?

Comment: Note that `git push` pushes *commits*, normally to a `--bare` repository on the server. This means that *no files change*. It's up to a deployment script on the server to extract and install files from the pushed commit(s); that deployment script *should* co-ordinate with anything that is actively using those files. It's up to you (or whoever writes the deployment code) to deal with this. Git is not a deployment mechanism; using it as one is like using a wrench as a hammer: it might work for a while but it's not a good idea.

Comment: Sorry torek, the `git pull` on the remote server was implied. My question focused on what `git pull` would do for php scripts/threads already running.

Answer (score 2):

This answer may help:

> You cannot edit your program because it's compiled in memory. Any
>   modification to the source code will be active after you reload the
>   program. This means that you have to kill the process and reload the
>   script.

Found here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/213265

Comment: To clarify, "program" above can be interpreted as "Apache process". Good find!